# How can we package flask backend with react.js frontend and deliver it as a desktop application (.exe, .dmg, .tar etc.)

Tags: python-3.x, reactjs, flask, web-applications, pip

We just built a web-app which is using Flask as backend and react.js as frontend. We are serving frontend from Flask (Through static_folder) and a URI to return static contents using 'send_from_directory'. We want to deliver this web-app as a desktop application (i.e user can download it as .exe, .dmg or .tar file and double-click it to install needed libraries and start flask server which will in-turn serve front-end as well). After this step user can type in '0.0.0.0:5000' to land on front-end login page. What are possible ways to deliver web-app in this way OR is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using the [electron framework](https://electronjs.org/), and decouple your application into separate pieces. Electron turns your front-end code into a desktop application everyone can download (.exe, .dmg, etc.) and install. Not only does it do this, but it supports popular frameworks such as React.js, Angular, Vue + more!

Next, your users would connect from your electron app to your flask server deployed in the cloud and consume any data as needed for logging in, application logic, etc. You can find an authentication library [here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/17/desktop-app-electron-authentication).

The security implications of everyone downloading your production back-end code and database would be devastating. Especially if you are working with sensitive data such as API keys, database passwords. I hope I was of some help!! :)